# How to plot small function values in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I am trying to visualize two functions in pgfplots and I can't get my main message across that both end at the same point. How can I change this behaviour, preferably without additional external tools?

Here is my small example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0.0,
    xmax=2,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1.75,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left, 
    xlabel=control parameter $r$,
    ylabel=energy $(J)$, 
    ytick={}, yticklabels={},
    xtick={1},
    xticklabels={1},    
    restrict x to domain=0:2,
    ]   

    \addplot+[smooth,no marks, samples at={1.0,0.999,0.99,0.96,...,0.001,0}] {1.12*(1-x)^0.5};
    \addplot+[smooth, densely dashed, no marks,samples=1000]{1.75*(1-x)^0.5}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

With the following output:

[image]

Ideally both functions would end exactly at (1,0) but even with a high number of samples or explicitly giving the x value of 1.0 I can't get close. I tried using gnuplot alternatively but ran into the issue mentioned in [Improve pfgplots precision with gnuplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82090/improve-pfgplots-precision-with-gnuplot), that pgfplots does not discard unbounded coordinates from gnuplot.

For an exponent of exactly 1/2 the sqrt function yields better results but only works in this special case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sqrt` function instead of raising zero to the power of 0.5.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0.0,
    xmax=2,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1.75,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left, 
    xlabel=control parameter $r$,
    ylabel=energy $(J)$, 
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick={1},
    xticklabels={1},    
    restrict x to domain=0:2,
    ]   

    \addplot+[smooth,no marks, samples at={1.0,0.999,0.99,0.96,...,0.001,0}] {1.12*sqrt(1-x)};
    \addplot+[smooth, densely dashed, no marks,samples=1000]{1.75*sqrt(1-x)}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that helps for the exponent of exactly 0.5. In my plots the exponent varies between 0.3 and 1 so that this only works in specific cases.

Comment: @Alexander Better include it in the question. For me `\addplot+[no marks, domain=0:0.99999999,samples=500] gnuplot {1.12*(1-x)^0.3};` works without any problems.

Comment: Thank you, the combination of domain and samples together solves the problem!